# cancelEdit() is being called when trying to commit a TableCell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to commit a `TableCell`, but `cancelEdit()` is being called instead. This only happens if I make the `cell` go into its editing state by calling `tableView.edit()`.

I call `editCommit()` by:

```
private void handleKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        commitEdit(textField.getText());
    }
}
```

Why is `cancelEdit()` being called when the enter key is pressed? Manually clicking on the added blank row and trying to commit the cell by pressing enter works fine.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
        root.setCenter(new TableExample());
    }

    public class TableExample extends VBox {
        public TableExample() {
            TableView<Building> tableView = new TableView<>();
            tableView.setEditable(true);

            //adds a new blank row to table;
            Button add = new Button("add");
            add.setOnAction(e -> {
                Building newBuilding = new Building();
                tableView.getItems().add(0, newBuilding);
                tableView.edit(0, tableView.getColumns().get(0));

                //I tried focusing and selecting the row
                //but does not help.
                tableView.getFocusModel().focus(0);
                tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

            });

            getChildren().addAll(add, tableView);

            Building building = new Building();
            building.setName("Building 100");

            Function<Building, StringProperty> property = Building::nameProperty;

            TableColumn<Building, String> column = new TableColumn<>("name");
            column.setEditable(true);
            column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
            column.setCellFactory(p -> new EditingStringCell<>());

            tableView.getColumns().add(column);
            tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(building));
        }
    }

    public class EditingStringCell<S, T> extends TableCell<Building, String> {
        private TextField textField;

        public EditingStringCell() {
            setEditable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? null : item);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            System.out.println("start edit");
            super.startEdit();
            buildControl(getItem());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        private void buildControl(String item) {
            System.out.println("item: " + item);
            textField = new TextField();        
            textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, 
            this::handleKeyPressed);
            textField.setText(item == null ? "" : (item));
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(textField);
        }

        //whenever pressing enter on a new "blank" row
        //cancelEdit() gets called. But if you try again 
        //it works.
        private void handleKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            System.out.println("cancel edit");
            super.cancelEdit();
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
            System.out.println("commited: " + newValue);
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }

    public class Building {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you override cancelEdit() method? By just removing it the problem is solved and the changes are commited

Comment: @JKostikiadis If you click on a different cell without pressing enter, the cell that you originally clicked would still show the text field. CancelEdit()  calls setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

Comment: So you want to check if the field loses the focus without pressing enter and if so just discard the changes.. I see let me think about it

Comment: a) why re-invent the wheel? There's a TextFieldTableCell b) make sure to exit the xxEdit method if not/editing c) there are bunches of bugs around table (or other virtualized controls) editing ..

Comment: @kleopatra I need to test the cell with a predicate. If it fails the test I display a tooltip. It might be possible using TextFieldTableCell, but just making my own cell it not that much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, TableView (and the other virtualized controls) are very ill-behaved when it comes to [terminating an on-going edit](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089514): most of the time it cancels the edit when usability would require a commit.

In your example, there are two different (well-known) reasons

1. an edit is canceled deep down in the bowels when the items list is modified, here an item is added
2. an edit is canceled by the editing tableCell itself when it detects a change in the table's editing location

To see, I have added a couple of prints into your code:

To demonstrate issue 1:

- edit the first item
- click the add button
- expected: edited item is saved and new item starts editing
- actual: edited item is not saved, new item starts editing

The print out:

```
start edit 0 on id: 2
before adding: TablePosition [ row: 0, column: ... ]
cancel edit 0 on id: 2
start edit 0 on id: 2
start edit 0 on id: 14   // <- some slightly weird cell re-use
cancel edit 12 on id: 2  // <- triggers a cancel on the old, functional interference unknown
```

To demonstrate issue 2:

- add an item and edit any
- click on edit to start editing on another
- expected: first edit saved, second edit started
- actual: first edit cancelled, second edit started

With print out:

```
before starting edit on : 1
start edit 1 on id: 13
cancel edit 0 on id: 14
```

... and unfortunately, there is not much (to the extent of nothing) that can be done ...

Your example slightly modified:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/46396423/203657
 */
public class TableEditSO extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
        //root.setCenter(new TableExample());
        root.setCenter(getContent());
    }

    private Parent getContent() {
        TableView<Building> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        //adds a new blank row to table;
        Button add = new Button("add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> {
            Building newBuilding = new Building();
            // modifications to the items will cancel an edit
            System.out.println("before adding: " + tableView.getEditingCell());
            tableView.getItems().add(0, newBuilding);
            tableView.edit(0, tableView.getColumns().get(0));

            //I tried focusing and selecting the row
            //but does not help.
            tableView.getFocusModel().focus(0);
            tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        });

        Button edit = new Button("edit");
        edit.setOnAction(e -> {
            int size = tableView.getItems().size();
            if (size < 2) return;
            TablePosition pos = tableView.getEditingCell();
            int last = size - 1;
            if (pos != null) {
                int row = pos.getRow();
                if (row == last) {
                    //make certain we switch editing to another row
                    last--;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("before starting edit on : " + last);
            // starting edit on another item will cancel an edit
            tableView.edit(last, tableView.getColumns().get(0));
        });

        Building building = new Building();
        building.setName("Building 100");

        Function<Building, StringProperty> property = Building::nameProperty;

        TableColumn<Building, String> column = new TableColumn<>("name");
        column.setEditable(true);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        column.setCellFactory(p -> new EditingStringCell<>());

        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(building));

        VBox box = new VBox(10, add, edit, tableView);
        return box;
    }

    // don't extend without functional reason
    public class TableExample extends VBox {
        public TableExample() {
            TableView<Building> tableView = new TableView<>();
            tableView.setEditable(true);

            //adds a new blank row to table;
            Button add = new Button("add");
            add.setOnAction(e -> {
                Building newBuilding = new Building();
                System.out.println("before adding: " + tableView.getEditingCell());

                tableView.getItems().add(0, newBuilding);
                System.out.println("after adding: " + tableView.getEditingCell());
                tableView.edit(0, tableView.getColumns().get(0));
                System.out.println("after starting: " + tableView.getEditingCell());

                //I tried focusing and selecting the row
                //but does not help.
                tableView.getFocusModel().focus(0);
                tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

            });

            getChildren().addAll(add, tableView);

            Building building = new Building();
            building.setName("Building 100");

            Function<Building, StringProperty> property = Building::nameProperty;

            TableColumn<Building, String> column = new TableColumn<>("name");
            column.setEditable(true);
            column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
            column.setCellFactory(p -> new EditingStringCell<>());

            tableView.getColumns().add(column);
            tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(building));
        }
    }

    public static class EditingStringCell<S, T> extends TableCell<Building, String> {
        static int id ;
        private int myId;
        private TextField textField;

        public EditingStringCell() {
            // just to see re-use of cells
            myId = id++;
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            // not needed, it's true by default
            // setEditable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? null : item);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            if (isEditing()) {
                System.out.println("start edit " + getIndex() + " on id: " + myId);
                updateEditControl(getItem());

            }
        }

        private void updateEditControl(String item) {
            if (textField == null) {
                textField = new TextField();   
                // always use the highest abstract available
                // so use action instead of keyEvent
                textField.setOnAction(this::handleAction);
                //textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, 
                //        this::handleKeyPressed);
                setGraphic(textField);
            }
            textField.setText(item == null ? "" : (item));
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        private void handleAction(ActionEvent ae) {
            commitEdit(textField.getText());

        }

        //whenever pressing enter on a new "blank" row
        //cancelEdit() gets called. But if you try again 
        //it works.
        private void handleKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            System.out.println("cancel edit " + getIndex() + " on id: " + myId);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
            System.out.println("commited: " + newValue + " index: " + getIndex() + " on id: " + myId);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }

    public class Building {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

Comment: The plan was to have the whole row go into an editing state, which would have multiple cells all go into their editing state when adding a new item. I could no longer use TableView.edit() as it would call cancelEdit() on the prior cell. So It will be interesting to see how this could be implemented.

Comment: @jpell don't fight the system - it's designed to have zero or exactly one cell in editing state!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is caused inside the buildControl() method instead of using the previous TextField you creating a new one every time a new edit event is triggered. All you have to do is to move the TextField's initialization inside the EditingStringCell constructor.

I tested all ( I hope ) the situations. Adding a new row while editing, selecting another row while editing, committing changes everything works fine. Almost 6am here so my thoughts aren't very clear :P

Comment: Yeah I see your logic. But keep it simple ;) Happy to help